# Finding original command result from MD5 hash

Tags: hash, md5

Basically I hashed the result of the "date" command with md5sum:

`$date | md5sum`

The output is indeed in the likes of:

`e4c94362cd4fd71ec6aca78c7411bdc3  -`

My question was: is it possible to recover the result of the date command knowing the date pattern (except for maybe the minutes and seconds)?

I tried using john's mask option as well as a custom wordlist, without result.

Do you guys have any idea how we could pull that off?

Comment: Welcome! What you are describing is called a [hash pre-image attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack), ie given the output of a hash function, find the input. The dictionaries that come with John contain things that people commonly put in passwords. So unless it's common for people to use an exact date string (in that format) as their password, it probably won't be in the John word list.

Comment: This is a great question for your learning. In general, what you're trying to do is exactly what hash functions are designed to prevent. I encourage you to do some reading about md5 pre-image attacks. Do some learning, maybe write some code, you'll probably learn a ton in the process! (afaik, md5 is vulnerable to collision attacks, but nobody has yet found an efficient pre-image attack, so what you're looking for may not be possible).

Comment: @MikeOunsworth It is not a pre-image attack. To qualify as one it **would** be necessary to find an input that corresponds to some result for **any arbitrary** value and **would not** be necessary for the input to be in any particular format. Cracking the input is a different game than launching a true pre-image attack.

Answer (score 2):

The key aspect of hash functions that make them so useful is that they are one-way - it is very easy to hash an input and produce an output, but very difficult to convert a given output into a valid input. In other words, (in most cases) the best way to figure out what input was used to generate a given output is to guess-and-check.

The good news for you is that this can be automated, and MD5 is pretty fast - so you can guess-and-check many, many possible inputs.

Let's say you have an input in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", and you know the date component (but not the time, so "2019-12-10 ??:??:??"). There are only ~85k possible  distinct time values to check, so if you simply enumerate through all the possible values until you get a match, you'll only have to run an average of ~42k hashes. For single pass MD5, most modern systems will be able to run this in a fraction of a second.

So, while there's no way to reverse the hash, in this instance brute-forcing it is not all that compute intensive.

Comment: Minor detail: it's not quite clear to me from the question whether the OP actually knows the date or not.  The OP said "is it possible to recover the result of the date command knowing the date pattern (except for maybe the minutes and seconds)".  This could mean they know the date but not the time, but I think they mean that they know the pattern the date string is in, but don't know exactly how the time is formatted.  In that case a brute force is *much* trickier

Comment: well if you can try one day in under a second, you can try a year in a few mins and a decade in an hour or so; shouldn't take long since the date is presumably after computers were invented and common...

Comment: I don't know if nuking is needed - plenty of helpful data here

Comment: Hello guys, firstly thanks for your answers. My original post was written too quickly, I apologize. Indeed I know the date pattern, what I don't know is the time in the date. Basically I thought about brute-forcing the time, but using John the Ripper mask/wordlist generation was not conclusive for me (I lack skills tho).